# Health Bar With Plus signs /closed

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a code where the users health shows as plus signs but i need the box to be 40 - marks long. Plus signs can not go outside of them. The Hp_Cur is the amount of Plus signs there are.

```py
Hp_Cur = int(input("Enter current health: "))

Hp_Max = int(input("Enter Max health: "))


print ("/", "-"*40, "\\")

print ("|", "+"*Hp_Cur, "|")

print ("\\", "-"*40, "/")
```

Comment: I am unsure as to what you need help for? Would you like advice on how to create a health bar with the formatting, or would you like a program that tests Hp_Cur and limits it or both?

Comment: advice on how to create a health bar. So even if the current health was above 40 the + signs would still be contained within.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi KingVarric this is what I assume you want for the program:

-to make sure the plus signs are not bigger than the box

-make the last middle "|" same as the box

```py
#this is my interpretation of your problem
Hp_Cur = int(input("Enter current health: "))

Hp_Max = int(input("Enter Max health: "))
# you can input 40 to make it 40 marks long

if Hp_Cur > Hp_Max:
#do test and limit plus signs
    print("Your Current Hp is bigger than your Max Hp")
else:
    print ("/", "-"*Hp_Max, "\\")
    print ("|", "+"*Hp_Cur, " "*(Hp_Max-Hp_Cur) + "|")#" "*(40-Hp_Cur) adds the necessary spaces
    print ("\\", "-"*Hp_Max, "/")
```

Comment: It is, appreciate it.

Comment: Could you approve my answer to close this question and edit (Closed) in the title. No problem!